# Exception in Jackson JSON object deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

I've a Java Web application that implements a REST API using Jersey and Jackson and it's deployed as a Docker image based on the tomcat official Docker image.
There are some classes used as API body parameters and organized as a tree hierarchy with a String type field acting as type discriminator, declared with the *JsonTypeInfo* annotation.
I have two deployments of the same Docker image on two distinct server, the first is an Ubuntu 16.04 Server and the second a Centos 7.6.
Now, the method using the above mentioned classes as body parameter runs successfully on the Ubuntu server, while on the Centos server throws the following exception if the passed JSON object has the type field not as the first one:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonStreamContext.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonStreamContext;)V
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBufferReadContext.(TokenBufferReadContext.java:47)

This is the payload that is accepted from both servers:

```
{
    "type": "query",
    "size": 10
    ...
}
```

while this one is rejected from the Centos server:

```
{
    "size": 10
    "type": "query",
    ...
}
```

I've checked the jars in the two images and they are exactly the same with the same versions, the constructor method mentioned in the exception can be found in the *jackson-core-2.9.3* jar, there are no other versions of the library around.
Everything is ok if the type parameter is the first one in the JSON object, but unfortunately this cannot be guaranteed because the API is called from an IOS app that gives no control over fields order in JSON object marshalling.
I cannot figure out how the operating system can influence the execution of a containerized Java application, does anyone have any suggestion about which direction should I investigate?

**EDIT**: problem solved. The *jackson-core-2.9.3* jar was included in both the Tomcat lib folder and the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web application; for some unknown reason in the Centos instance this causes the method not found error, I simply removed the file from the WEB-INF/lib folder and the error disappeared. It would be interesting to investigate if it could be a Java bug.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? I read it to mean that you send a *different* request to your CentOs server than to your Ubuntu server, or do you mean the Ubuntu server behaves correctly for both tests, but CentOs fails for one? It might also be useful to show a sample of the message to illustrate.

Comment: Are you sure that the Tomcat container doesn't come with its own, older copy of Jackson?

Comment: @chrylis The two Docker images are identical, so the Jackson libraries are identical for the two containers, but one runs successfully, the other gives the error.

Comment: @andrew-g-za The Ubuntu server behaves correctly with both requests, while the Centos server only accepts requests with the type field as the first field in the JSON, fails in other cases

Comment: @andrew-g-za I have edited my question adding two examples of accepted and rejected payload.

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset explicitly in the request? You might have some encoding problems there. It's a long shoot

Comment: I see the method that its failing on is documented as being added in v2.9. If we assume assume the stack trace is correct, then the only explanation is that the docker image you are using on the CentOs VM does not have the correct library versions. I don't know too much about Docker images, perhaps you made changes along the way and somehow didnt sync the latest, or the one you are using is 'cached' - try stop the container, remove it and download it again to make sure the container you are using truly is identical on the two VMs.

Comment: @andrew-g-za I went exactly through the steps you suggested, now the two images are identical, I checked files one by one, the problem is still there.